# Ignore directory path in find (in shell)

Tags: shell, find

I'm trying to find files in some dir and ignore some path.

`cd /some/dir && find . -type f ! -path ./media` doesn't work. Where is a mistake?

Any directory with the same name in subdirs shouldn't be ignored. E.g.`/some/media/`.

P.S. Also mask `./media/*` does not work too.

P.P.S Yeah, I know I can use `grep` like `grep -vE "^(\./dir1|\./dir2)"`. Any chance to use find only?

Comment: `! -path ./media ` is only false for the exact directory (or file) `./media`, it's still true for anything in that directory (e.g. `./media/somefile`). You want `find . -type f ! -path ./media ! -path './media/*'` or `find . -path ./media -prune -o -type f -print` (this will actually stop traversing the directory rather than just not printing it, though both should produce the same output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-regex` option:

```
find -type f ! -regex '.*/media/.*'
```

Comment: `.*/media/.*` should be just `./media/.*` (first `.` may need to be escaped too) to meet the `Any directory with the same name in subdirs shouldn't be ignored`

Comment: Yeah, agree. I use dot in the beginning.